# Python Pandas append to concat within a custom function with loops?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, append

So I learned that my version of Python doesn't take append, which was in the original code:

```
def getDataForDateRange(date_Index_New, rows):
    WeeklyStockDataRows = pd.DataFrame()
    for I in date_Index_New:
        WeeklyStockDataRows = WeeklyStockDataRows.append(\
          rows.iloc[rows.index.get_loc(I, method="nearest")])
    return WeeklyStockDataRows
```

This obviously produces the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I learned that changing it to concat works. But is this the correct code? I ask because my data output has been empty, which could be caused by another issue.

```
def getDataForDateRange(date_Index_New, rows):
    WeeklyStockDataRows = pd.DataFrame()
    for I in date_Index_New:
        I_datetime = pd.to_datetime(I)  
        nearest_index = (rows.index - I_datetime).argmin()
        WeeklyStockDataRows = pd.concat(
            [WeeklyStockDataRows, rows.iloc[[nearest_index]]]
        )
    return WeeklyStockDataRows
```

Comment: No, it's not. Never use `concat` in a loop, the complexity is quadratic. Instead, collect the new rows in a `list` and `concat` only once after the loop.